# Compare two objects and add differences without manipulating existing ones

Tags: javascript

I have an object that looks like this:

```
var obj = {
  1: {
    'x': [ [], [], [] ],
    'y': [ [], [] ],
  },
  2: {
    'x': [ [], [] ],
    'z': [ [] ],
  },  
}
```

I also have another object which I want to get differences and add into it.

```
var newObj = {};
```

I want to compare this object with another object, and get the differences. I want to evaluate only the 'integer' key level and 'letter' key level, not the inner children.

According to the difference, add missing ones and remove deleted ones too. However, while doing that difference, I want to to only add new keys and values like this: `'new': [ [] ]`, but keep the existing ones if they exist and doesn't touch them. Only add missing key with empty array value.

Is there a way to do that?

Here is a fiddle where I explained more in detail with examples:
https://jsfiddle.net/7ccd3una/1/

---

If:

```
var newObj = {
  1: {
    'x': [ [], [], [] ],
  },
  2: {
    'z': [ [] ],
  },  
}
```

and obj is

```
var obj = {
  1: {
    'x': [ [], [], [] ],
    'y': [ [], [] ],
  },
  2: {
    'x': [ [], [] ],
    'z': [ [] ],
  },  
}
```

After the function call, I want newObj to be like this (add only 1 empty array for new ones):

```
newObj = {
  1: {
    'x': [ [], [], [] ],
    'y': [ [] ]
  },
  2: {
    'x': [ [] ],
    'z': [ [] ],
  },  
}
```

---

Full Example:

```
newObj = {} // just initialised.

obj = {
  1: {
    'x': [ [], [], [] ],
    'y': [ [] ]
  },
}

// newObj becomes, 

newObj : {
  1: {
    'x': [ [] ],
    'y': [ [] ]
  },
}

// This newObj can get structured itself. So it can become like:

newObj : {
  1: {
    'x': [ [], [], [] ],
    'y': [ [] ]
  },
}
// ..separately from the obj.

// So I want to watch the letter key adds and removes actually. Let's say obj became:

obj : {
  1: {
    'x': [ [] ],
    'y': [ [] ],
    'd': [ [], [] ],
  },
  2: {
    'a': [ [], [], [] ],
    'b': [ [], [] ]
  }
}

// I want newObj to be:

newObj : {
  1: {
    'x': [ [], [], [] ],
    'y': [ [] ],    // don't do anything to existings
    'd': [ [] ],    // add empty array for new letter key
  },
  2: {
    'a': [ [] ],  // add empty array for letter key
    'b': [ [] ]   //  ""
  }
}

// And if items removed:
obj : {
  1: {
    'x': [ [] ]
}

// newObj becomes:
 newObj: {
    1: {
      'x': [ [], [], [] ]
    }
 }
```

Comment: How are you comparing the arrays? By reference? Because based on how you've defined your object, they're not re-using the same object references, so all of the nested arrays will be _different_.

Comment: I want them to be different. All I want is add the newly added ones (letters) with an empty array value, do nothing to existing ones, or remove it entirely if letter key is removed.

Comment: The last two examples are a bit confusing.  Can you rewrite it as before and after just like the top two examples. https://jsfiddle.net/7ccd3una/2/

Comment: Here it is. https://jsfiddle.net/7ccd3una/3/ Hope it is more clear

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
function copy(obj, newObj) {


var keys = Object.keys(obj)
keys.map(function(val){

if(newObj.hasOwnProperty(val)){

var keys_two = Object.keys(obj[val])

keys_two.map(function(prop){
   if(!newObj.hasOwnProperty(prop)){
      var data_two = obj[val][prop]
      newObj[val][prop] = data_two;
   
   }
})
} else {
   var data = obj[val]
   newObj[val] = data;
 
}

})

}
```

Here is on [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0n9m9kgp/)

Comment: Let me know if there is anything missing

Comment: Thanks for your time. However, I don't want it to copy it exactly. If added, I want to add with only 1 empty array child, not how many there is. I have updated my question, please check it also

Comment: So basically, add the new key with an empty array, `'new': [ [] ] ` without considering its value on original array. Also if it is removed, just remove it too

Comment: basically that sounds like you literally making a duplicate of the original object to a new object right?

Comment: Not really the duplicate.. The adding/removing from the obj is binded to a checkbox, so it either addeds or removes one at a time. So, i want to observe the letter key levels not the values. If a new letter-key is added, I want to add it to my newObj object with an empty array value. Like this: `'new': [ [] ]`, without touching the other ones. If added to an empty array value added to an existing letter key, don't do anything. If a letter key is deleted, delete that letter key and value entirely. Is it more clear now? (btw, thanks for spending time on my question. i'm grateful for your help)

Comment: Also for your fiddle, would be like this: `newObj : { 1: { 'x': [ [] ], 'y': [ [] ] }, 2: { 'x': [ [] ], 'z': [ [] ] } }`